# How do i view the parsed json data from odoo api in the listview?

Tags: api, flutter, odoo

i am not able to view the json in the listview. it might be a problem with return type. The list i.e 'users' I am returning doesn't return any data, so when i call the function in the FutureBuilder widget, i get null.

```
 OdooResponse result;
 List<Saleslist> users = [];
 Future<List<Saleslist>> _getOrders() async {
   var client = OdooClient("http://192.168.1.108:8050");
   final domain = [
     // ["sale_ok", "!=", false]
   ];
   var fields = ["id", "name"];
   // var fields = ["id", "name", "confirmation_date"];

   client
       .authenticate("admin", "admin", "flutterodoo11")
       .then((AuthenticateCallback auth) async {
     if (auth.isSuccess) {
       final user = auth.getUser();
       print("Hey ${user.name}");
     } else {
       // login fail
       print("Login failed");
     }

     client
         .searchRead("sale.order", domain, fields)
         .then((OdooResponse result) {
       if (!result.hasError()) {
         print("Succesful");
         var response = result.getResult();
         var encoded = json.encode(response['records']);
         data = encoded;
         var convertDataToJson = json.decode(encoded);
         data = convertDataToJson;
         print(data);

         for (var u in data) {
           print(u);
           Saleslist user = Saleslist(u["name"], u["id"]);
           users.add(user);
         }
       } else {
         print(result.getError());
       }
       print(users.length);
     });
   });
   return users;
 }
```

This is the code for Future Builder

```
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _getOrders(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    print(data);
                    return Container(
                        child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ));
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data.name),
                          );
                        });
                  }
                  // }
                }),
          ),
```

This is the json i get from the odoo_api
`[{id: 1, name: SO001}, {id: 2, name: SO002}, {id: 3, name: SO003}, {id: 5, name: SO005}, {id: 4, name: SO004}, {id: 7, name: SO007}, {id: 9, name: SO008}, {id: 10, name: SO009}, {id: 6, name: SO006}, {id: 8, name: Test/001}, {id: 11, name: SO010}, {id: 12, name: SO011}, {id: 13, name: SO012}, {id: 14, name: SO013}, {id: 15, name: SO014}, {id: 16, name: SO015}, {id: 17, name: SO016}, {id: 18, name: SO017}, {id: 19, name: SO018}, {id: 20, name: SO019}]`

EDIT:

Now i'm getting "Another exception was thrown: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'" error... i added the await method, but the FutureBuilder widget is the same.

```
var client = OdooClient("http://192.168.1.34:8050");
  List<Saleslist> users = [];
  var data;
  OdooResponse result;
  Future<List<Saleslist>> _getOrders() async {
    final domain = [
      // ["sale_ok", "!=", false]
    ];
    var fields = ["id", "name"];

    // var fields = ["id", "name", "confirmation_date"];
    await client
        .authenticate("admin", "admin", "flutterodoo11")
        .then((AuthenticateCallback auth) async {
      if (auth.isSuccess) {
        final user = auth.getUser();
        print("Hey ${user.name}");
      } else {
        // login fail
        print("Login failed");
      }

      await client
          .searchRead("sale.order", domain, fields)
          .then((OdooResponse result) {
        if (!result.hasError()) {
          print("Succesful");
          var response = result.getResult();
          var encoded = json.encode(response['records']);
          // data = json.encode(encoded);
          data = json.decode(encoded);
          print(data);

          for (var u in data) {
            // print(u);
            Saleslist user = Saleslist(u["name"], u["id"]);
            users.add(user);
          }
        } else {
          print(result.getError());
        }
      });
    });
    print(users.length);
    return (users);
  }
```

Comment: it would be *much* easier to use `await` inside `_getOrders` method (instead of two `then` methods)

Comment: I'm new to flutter. I'm not exactly sure how to implement await in my code. Could you please explain it a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: read https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures (and this: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await in particular) - also you could read https://codingwithjoe.com/dart-fundamentals-async-await/ too

Comment: Could you post a snippet to change the then to await. It's not working for me still.

Comment: probably the syntax of where exactly should i use the await. the code i posted above is pretty much it. rest are imports and scaffold parts.

Comment: I'm getting a new error, i've edited the post.

Comment: if you are using `await` then you doint have to use `then()` method, did you really read the links i posted? they have  a lot of examples on how to use `await`

Comment: yeah, i removed the then() method and have updated the post.. but still i get the <List<Slaeslist>> is not the subtype of type <String> error. Is there somthing i'm doing wrong while removing the then() method? or is it something else.

Comment: @pskink i solved the issue.. thanks for suggesting the use of await. it took time, but i managed to use it correctly. now the sales order are showing in the ListView. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usign await instead of then() solved the return type (i think) issue.

```
var client = OdooClient("http://192.168.1.108:8050");
  Future<List<Saleslist>> _getOrders() async {
    // List<Saleslist> users = [];

    final domain = [];
    // var fields = ["id", "name"];
    var fields = ["id", "name", "confirmation_date", "partner_id"];
    AuthenticateCallback auth =
        await client.authenticate("admin", "admin", "flutterodoo11");
    if (auth.isSuccess) {
      final user = auth.getUser();
      print("Hey ${user.name}");
    } else {
      // login fail
      print("Login failed");
    }

    OdooResponse result = await client.searchRead("sale.order", domain, fields);
    if (!result.hasError()) {
      print("Successful");
      var response = result.getResult();
      var data = json.encode(response['records']);
      // data = json.encode(encoded);
      var decoded = json.decode(data);
      print(data);
      List<Saleslist> users = [];
      for (var u in decoded) {
        // print(u);
        Saleslist user = Saleslist(u["name"], u["id"]);
        print(user);
        users.add(user);
      }
      return users;
    } else {
      print(result.getError());
    }
  }
```

The snapshot.data was a string when "List" type was expected. Thus changing it as "snapshot.data[index].name" solved the entire issue of not showing data in the list view.

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: _getOrders(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.data);
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  // print(snapshot.data);
                  return Container(
                      child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                } else {
                  return SizedBox(
                    // height: 500,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          return Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                              title: Text(
                                snapshot.data[index].name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  // fontFamily: "Hand_Of_Sean_Demo",
                                ),
                              ),
                              // subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].partner_id),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                }
                // }
              }),
```

Comment: @ Rojan Shresstha: Hi. Can you please add complete code about how to fetch products from odoo api and display it in flutter. Is there any video or github link about this? please share me.It would be great if you help me. thanks

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir i have not used odoo_api in a while now.. so if there were any changes made in the api, i am not aware of them. before, there was searchRead() method and others to read data from odoo and we could store the data and show it using the FutureBuilder() or you could save the data in a provider etc and display it accordingly. But right now, i dont exactly know if those methods are available in the odoo_api or not. You could check [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/odoo_api/latest/odoo_api/OdooClient-class.html) for some information